# How can i handle bcc information with qmail?

Tags: email, smtp, thunderbird, bcc, qmail

I use qmail, and i send a mail with Thunderbird or Outlook. I can handle to, from, body, cc informations with qmail. But i cannot handle bcc. Because people say "qmail stripts out bcc." Some other people says "it is not job of qmail ( mta) , problem is from thunderbird (mua), it strips out bcc ". I don't know which is true.

So, How can i handle bcc information with qmail , Can you explain ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to distinguish between receivers in header and in smtp-envelope. What you use as "To", "Cc" end up as header fields in your mail and are also used as envelope receipients in SMTP. The header fields are merely informational and are not used for message delivery. For "Bcc", your MUA (e.g. Thunderbird) does not include a header field in the mail, but only uses a corresponding envelope-receipient when handing over the message to the mail server. Adding Bcc information to the mail itself actually would defeat its purpose. Therefore, no information about this receiver is contained in the message itself. So qmail does not "strip out bcc" from the mail, since was never there, but it will be able to deliver the mail anyway.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I controlled pcap file. Can you have a solution handling of bcc ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by handling. Normally, no special handling is required. The Bcc-recipient will get the message without further action or cnfiguration , and all other's won't know. That's exactly what Bcc should do.